# How to attach recessed light fixture flat to ceiling

Tags: electrical, lighting

One of two recessed light fixtures in our kitchen is detached from the ceiling. I think there must have been a part (possibly a spring hook, but I don't know) that came undone when a new light bulb was installed. I don't want to create another problem by trying to detach the other light to examine the mechanism. Is there an adhesive that would work? Or another way to jerry rig a spring like type of attachment? [image]

Comment: If you can tell us the brand/model of the light we might be persuaded to look up the instructions for you. Based on those, you'll know what king of attaching system it _had_, so you'll know what kind of system to rig up. You definitely do _NOT_ want to glue it to the ceiling. Not unless you want to do ceiling repair at some point in the future.

Comment: We moved into the house with the fixtures installed. Only thing I could see is the brand Feit. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

Those MR16 Halogen lamps get extremely hot while in use and the thin metal spring clips that hold them in the housing like to become brittle and break off after a while.  I have fashioned a lot of replacement clips from other metal left over from various projects.  All you really need is something to take up space and provide enough friction to hold the lamp in.  (Do not use something that will burn or melt - I had a coworker use several wraps of electrical tape to hole one of those up once - what a disgusting mess that was.)

I know you didn't ask, but you might consider swapping those halogens out for LED MR16 while you're replacing them.  The reduction in heat cycling and longer times between bulb replacements will help keep you from having to hack those housings back together as often, not to mention the energy savings.

Comment: I appreciate the help and suggestion. In terms of swapping out for LEDs not sure I can take on another project just now. Yeah, thought it might be possible to make couple clips from random parts in my tool box.

Comment: Sounds like you could get MR16 LED bulbs, @Michael, and just swap them out as the halogens die, or buy a box of 10 and replace the 10 in the most commonly used areas of the house, then do another 10 in a month or two. Lather. Rinse. Repeat until the whole house has been swapped over.